# How to configure CDI in jersey 2.x version?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, cdi, glassfish-4

I often encountering the deployment issue with the glass fish. It is showing CDI deployment failure at injector resource.

I am connecting to the data base through glass fish jdbc connection pool. and Injecting the data source using @inject annotations, does this causing CDI ?

I haven't configured beans.xml file.

Comment: If you could show some code? And make sure you dont have beans.xml file in your classpath? or within your libraries (guava is sometimes notorious with this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably victim of this issue: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-377

I'm just guessing since you didn't provide the version of Glassfish you are using.
This issue has been fixed in CDI 1.2 which is included in Glassfish 4.1. So the best solution would be to update to this version.

If you can't or don't want to update you can use this workaround: http://weld.cdi-spec.org/documentation/#4